# If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ measurable and negative, there is a sequence $(\varphi _n)$ of simple function s.t. $\varphi _n\nearrow f$

Tags: measure-theory

> **Theorem:** I know that if $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is measurable and positive, there is a sequence of simple function $(\varphi _n)$ s.t. $\varphi _n(x)\nearrow f(x)$. I kniw that this result is not true if $f$ is not positive.

**My question :**

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ measurable. Let $f\leq 0$ and $$\varphi _n(x)=\frac{\left\lfloor 2^n f(x)\right\rfloor }{2^n}\vee (-n),$$
where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor function and $a\vee b$ denote the maximum between $a$ and $b$. We have that $$\varphi _n(x)\to f(x)$$
and that $\varphi _n$ is increasing even since $$\varphi _n(x)=\frac{\lfloor 2^n f(x)\rfloor }{2^n}\leq \frac{2^{n}f(x)}{2^n}=\frac{2^{n+1}f(x)}{2^{n+1}},$$ 
and thus $\varphi _n(x)\leq \varphi _{n+1}(x) $.

Why is this theorem is not true if $f<0$ ? The fact that there is a sequence of simple $\varphi _n(x)\nearrow f(x)$ looks true even if $f\leq 0$, no ?

Comment: The term on the rhs of your inequality is not $\varphi_{n+1}(x)$.

Comment: But we have the integer $2\lfloor a\rfloor \le 2a$, thus $2\lfloor a\rfloor\le\lfloor 2a\rfloor$. Here $a=2^nf(x)$.

Comment: $\frac{\left\lfloor 2^n f(x)\right\rfloor }{2^n}$ is not a simple function, regardless of whether $f\ge0$.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be true if $f$ is not bounded below. Because a simple function is certainly bounded below, and if $\phi_n$ increases to $f$ then $f\ge\phi_1$.

Comment: Yes true, so take $\varphi _n=\frac{\lfloor 2^nf(x)\rfloor }{2^n}\vee(-n)$ if $f<0$.

Comment: Then $\varphi _n\nearrow f$ no ?

Comment: @user659895 No! **If $f$ is not bounded below there is no sequence of simple functions insreasing to $f$**. The proof is very simple - above. You can't make that fact into a non-fact by defining $\phi_n$ properly,

Comment: @user659895 With the specific $\phi_n$ you suggest (which btw need not be simple functions) you don't have $\phi_{n+1}\ge\phi_n$,

Comment: You right, it's indeed not increasing. But It's simple since $\varphi _n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n2^n}\frac{-k}{2^n}\boldsymbol 1_{\{\frac{-k}{2^n}<f(x)\leq \frac{-k+1}{2^n}\}}(x)-n\boldsymbol 1_{f(x)\leq -n}(x)$ isn't it true ?

Comment: The $\phi_n$ in your latest comment is not the same as $\frac{\left\lfloor 2^n f(x)\right\rfloor }{2^n}\vee (-n)$. (Unless $f\le0$.)

Comment: True, it should rather be $\varphi _n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n2^n}\frac{-k}{2^n}\boldsymbol 1_{\frac{-k}{n}\leq f(x)<\frac{-k+1}{n}}(x)-n\boldsymbol 1_{\{f(x)<-n\}}(x)$, but still, it is a simple function, no ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we take a measurable function such as $f(x) = -1/|x|$ (defined to be, say, $0$ at the origin). For any simple function $\phi$, since $\phi$ has finite range, we know that there is an interval $I = (0,\epsilon)$ such that $f < \phi$ on $I$.

Therefore, if $(\phi_n)_n$ is any sequence of simple functions with $\phi_n \leq \phi_{n+1}$, then this sequence cannot converge pointwise everywhere to $f$, since for any $n$, $f(x) < \phi_1(x) \leq \phi_n(x)$ in a suitable interval $I$.

Note that the problem with your construction is that the $\phi_n$ are not always simple; in the case of the $f$ above, the range is not finite.

Comment: Yes, just take $\varphi _n(x)\frac{\lfloor 2^n f(x)\rfloor }{2^n}\vee(-n)$ if $f<0$. Then for sure $\varphi _n(x)\leq f(x)$ and $\varphi _n$ is increasing... and it converges everywhere to $f(x)$.

Comment: @user659895 How do you show $\phi_n$ is increasing? (And btw what makes you think $\phi_n$ is simple?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: because if $f<0$, $$\varphi _n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{-k}{n}\boldsymbol 1_{\{\frac{-k}{n}\leq f(x)<\frac{-k+1}{n}\}}-n\boldsymbol 1_{\{f(x)<-n\}}$$ which is simple, no ?

Answer (score -2):

This result is true even for $f \leq 0$. What was probably meant is that you can't use this method to integrate functions that aren't positive almost everywhere.

Comment: When you say it's true does that mean you know how to prove it or just that you don't see why it shouldn't be true?